# I'm unsure of what DNM means on this schematic

Tags: bluetooth

I looked up DNM Capacitors; however, everyone I saw had a footprint that was to large to be in this circuit. I also thought that it could mean "Does not matter" but that seems kind of silly to put into a schematic. The IC is a CC2640 which is a wireless MCU. Thanks for any help that is offered! [image]

Comment: I would say "Do not mount". these should not be populated in the given configuration.

Comment: I've also seen "DNP"  (do not populate), and my Chinese colleagues seem to be fond of "N/C"  (which really means "no connect' usually, but hey these guys don't speak English so I don't split hairs....)

Comment: BTW, these are, if used, probably in the neighborhood of 7-20pF capacitors.  Would depend on the crystal oscillator used (it's datasheet would tell you the value of capacitors it requires)

Comment: @KyleB For the crystal caps yes, but the ones on the power rails can be, and most likely are, much larger than that.

Comment: @Aaron   Right - I didn't see those.   Good eye.   I only saw the ones on the crystal.  The ones on the rails could almost anything, but probably (IMO) reserved as something around 0.1uF, just to soak up any little bit of high-frequency noise that might exist.

Comment: At my company, `DNI` means "do not install" (i.e. purchase the part to include in pack-out, but do not mount on board, like a spare part or optional mounting hardware) ; `DNP` means "do not procure / do not purchase". We have also used `OPEN` but sometimes that causes confusion about whether to purchase/packout or omit from the purchase bom. These abbreviations are only semi-standard, and should be spelled out in a boilerplate note on the schemtaic or bill of materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parts labeled DNM most likely means "Do Not Mount".

The parts are drawn in the schematics and on the PCB board, but the components are not placed on the board during manufacture.

They are left out if not needed for a certain board revision, but if later changes need to be made, it means that existing boards can still be used after updating the Bill Of Materials.

For example if the RTC crystal changes for some reason, then the capacitors can be placed there if necessary.